# chrome select network connection to use based on URL

Tags: google-chrome

I'm not sure which StackExchange to ask this on, so I'll start with this one, and if voted down I'll remove the question.

I want get Chrome to select a network connection to use based on URL.

For example. 
If I want to go to www.bob.com, then use wifi.
If I want to go to www.jane.com, then use cabled connection.

Why do I hear you ask? Because I get different privileges at work on different connections.

I've looked at Switchy, but that only does connection switching for VPN connections.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Its been a while, and I've now found a solution to this.

ForceBindIP

http://www.r1ch.net/stuff/forcebindip/

Download it, stick it in the Windows\System32 folder.

Find the GUID of the Network card you want to use (via RegEdit) and run this command...

C:\Windows\System32\ForceBindIP.exe {5CBB6FC0-3C9D-43C4-A166-0CB41387F7E8} "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"

Bingo, firefox is bound only to the Wireless card.

Why? Because the wireless network at work is un-restricted, wired is restricted.
So when I want to get to a blog entry that Google promises to solve all my problems, then its time to fire up Firefox.